# why do my ConstraintLayout work like this? (things swap position)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image: the problem's pic (gif)]

I am really new to android development, learning from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui)

So stick to the tutorial, I want to make a ConstraintLayout and chain my textbox and button1, but you can see it in that pic. when I'm doing that, they swap position!

I really don't know how to solve that.

Comment: provide some xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select three view and then "Create horizontal chain" which link view in horizontal only.
Chain will rearrange all view relation to horizontal or vertical.
Read more about constraint chain [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)

//Solution 
If you need to set chain between EditText and Button just pick only both of them.

Comment: *thonk* but I did only pick two.... what is the third one i picked? thanks anyway ,I will try only to pick two

Answer (score 1):

[image: select them in component tree！]
working for me if i select them in "Component Tree" instead of selecting them on blueprint !

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="36dp"
        android:hint="Enter email ID"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/signInBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/emailId"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/emailId" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]